# Discord.py cant load cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i tried to link the cogs in my main.py. But it always give an error.
We also Check if some package are missing but it dont.
The bot start without the listdir but after we try to link it it doesnt work.
we also write:
class Help(commands.Cog):
def **init**(self, client):
self.client = client
Into the whole py's. But still not working.

```
import discord
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import importlab
import importlib
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "Tokeninhere"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix ="!")
PREFIX = "!"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=F"{PREFIX}help")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)

  
for filename in os.listdir('./Cog'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'./Cog/{filename[:-3]}')
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

The Error that pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'./Cog/{filename[:-3]}')
  File "/home/runner/Tijon-Bot-Main/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 670, in load_extension
    name = self._resolve_name(name, package)
  File "/home/runner/Tijon-Bot-Main/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 629, in _resolve_name
    return importlib.util.resolve_name(name, package)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 32, in resolve_name
    raise ValueError(f'no package specified for {repr(name)} '
ValueError: no package specified for './Cog/mods' (required for relative module names)

```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `load_extension` has an optional `package` parameter that should be specified when using relative imports see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 client.load_extension(f'Cog.{filename[:-3]}')
```

And make sure you have a setup function in your cog.

```
def setup(bot):
    client.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Comment: So i just use ur code but its now says: discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'Cog.levels' has no 'setup' function. i put in the Setup function in my cog but it still give me an Error.

Comment: Add setup functions to all your cogs for example if your cogs' class name is Levels you would add:
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Levels(bot))

Comment: Also I just noticed that your bot variable is named client so it should be `client.add_cog()` instead.